# Installing coredns on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, coredns

New Amazon EKS clusters created with Kubernetes version 1.11 ship with CoreDNS as the default DNS. I was wondering if:

1. GKE plans to do the same
2. Has anyone posted instructions on how to install coredns in GKE

Comment: not sure about GKE plans but see these articles for migration instructions: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/ https://coredns.io/2018/05/21/migration-from-kube-dns-to-coredns/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to changing it, there are several guide, for [example this one](https://medium.com/google-cloud/coredns-afaa732aa35e).

Also, in this official page of Kubernetes you can find [how to install CoreDNS instead of kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/).

TL:DR:

In Kubernetes version 1.10 and later:

```
kubeadm upgrade apply v1.11.0 --feature-gates=CoreDNS=true
```

In Kubernetes version 1.13 and later the CoreDNS feature gate is removed and CoreDNS is used by default

Comment: GKE is still stuck on kube-dns, even on k8s 1.13. Even the GKE v1.14.x alpha is still on kube-dns. (Source: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes). I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Update: After years of Kubernetes versions, GKE is still stuck on kube-dns at GKE v1.27, and they don't exactly let you disable its components and use CoreDNS instead.

Answer (score 0):

coredns has an auto generating deployment script.

to install coredns and disable kube-dns, try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/coredns/deployment.git
cd deployment/kubernetes
./deploy.sh > corends-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f corends-deployment.yaml
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/kube-dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
```

and then you can test it with this:

```
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
```